# Github connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: git, terminal

I suddenly started getting the following error message while attempting to push or pull:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I check If I have the "correct access rights"? I've been working on this repository for quite some time and never had issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `telnet github.com 22` --- what would you get if you run it?

Comment: @zerkms I get `Operation timed out`, `Unable to connect to remote host`

Comment: It's something with your connection then.

Comment: @zerkms any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: It can be anything: from problems with your OS to problems with your internet provider.

Comment: @zerkms : ssh -T git@github.com works for me. It says "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Answer (score 11):

Don't know if someone still needs a solution to this. Went through the same problem and I found a solution with the link below.

Create or edit `~/.ssh/config` and append the following:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

You can read from here: https://amesbury.it/git/github/2018/05/15/port22-blocked-github.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by removing the github entry from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.